# TextInput ref won't work -- got ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a component with a bunch of `TextInput` fields.
They all have this kind of structure:

```
...
<TextInput
  style={styles.mediumFont}
  placeholder="Please enter patient's name..."
  value={patient_name}
  onChangeText={(text) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, patient_name: text })
  }
  onSubmitEditing={() => {
    doctorNameField.focus();
  }}
/>
...
<TextInput
  ref={input=>doctorNameField=input}
  style={styles.mediumFont}
  placeholder="Please enter doctor's name..."
  value={doctor_name}
  onChangeText={(text) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, doctor_name: text })
  }
  onSubmitEditing={() => {
    PrescribsionField.focus();
  }}
/>
...
```

The pattern of how I used `ref` and `onSubmitEditing` worked in other component, but I am not sure why this one didn't...

Please help! Much appreciated!

Comment: Not 100% sure, but shouldn't you set the reference by doing `ref={input => this.doctorNameField=input}`
And then focusing like this `this.doctorNameField.focus();`

Comment: it says `this` is undefined